# how to get values from json and get access to it the basic

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

this is how am using the ajax

```
$.get('checkanswer.php',{'clickedvalue':clickedvalue,'qid':qid},function(data){
                $this.find(".report").html(data);
```

and this is my PHP code from where data is coming

```
<?php
$countresult=0;
$questionid=$_GET['qid'];
$answer=$_GET['clickedvalue'];
$dbconnect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','quiz')or die("Error Connecting to database");
$query="select answer from question_answer where id=$questionid";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbconnect,$query);
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $dbanswer=$rows['answer'];
    }
    if($dbanswer==$answer)
        {
        echo "Correct";
        $countresult=$countresult+1;
        }
    else{
        echo "Incorrect";
        $countresult=$countresult-1;
    }   

?>
```

Now previously i was just checking the result is correct or not and displaying tha result but now i want the PHP page to return even the variable that store the counts that is stored in $countresult. I know I have to use json but how to use it in PHP page ,pass the value and get access to that value from another page ,

Answer (score 1):

In your php:

```
$data = array('countresult' => $countresult);
$str = json_encode($data);
echo $str;
```

In your js:

```
$.get('checkanswer.php',{'clickedvalue':clickedvalue,'qid':qid},function(data){
       alert(data['countresult']);
}, "json");
```

Document about [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: when i alert the data array value its showing undefined value what do i do

Comment: Sorry for replying your comment so later, I was on a trip. I updated the answer, `jQuery.get()` should indicate the datatype from server. We use json data format here.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode in php

```
 <?php
 $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

 echo json_encode($arr);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put messages in an array normally:

```
$server_response['error'] = "something";
$server_response['Success'] = "some other thing";
$sever_response['vars'] = "blah blah";
echo json_encode($server_response);
```

Then from js if your response variable is ServerResponse, you can access as

```
ServerResponse.error or
ServerResponse.Success or
ServerResponse.vars
```